# Disable Serving from Default Cloudfront Hostname (ourdistid.cloudfront.net)

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I've setup an alternate domain name for our Cloudfront distribution so we can serve from oursite.com.  We'd like to disable ourdistid.cloudfront.net so our site is only accessible from one hostname.  Is this possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible. Out of curiosity - why do you want to do it?

Comment: Seems less brittle than using  <link rel="canonical"> for preventing duplicate content.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do this, though perhaps not in the place where you might expect to.

By default, CloudFront sets the `Host:` header in the request sent to the origin server to have the value of the *origin server hostname.*

However, you can configure CloudFront to forward the original request's host header to the origin server, instead.  It doesn't change how the request is routed, only the header that gets forwarded.

After that, it is a simple matter to configure your web server to return the response you want, when the request's `Host:` header matches the *.cloudfront.net host, which can include a generic error page with whatever code you seem most appropriate, such as 503 Service Unavailable, 404 Not Found, 403 Forbidden, or 410 Gone.  You could even use 301 Moved Permanently.  Whatever makes the most sense to you.

You can't literally disable the assigned endpoint, but you can prevent it from returning any of your content.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html